# Cannot infer template argument 'T' when a second parameter includes 'T'

Tags: c++

Given this template function:

```cpp
template <
    typename T,
    typename U,
    typename = std::enable_if<
        std::is_same_v<U, std::unique_ptr<T>> ||
        std::is_same_v<U, std::shared_ptr<T>>>>
T foo(U val) {
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<U, std::unique_ptr<T>>) {
    return *val;
  }
  return *val;
}
```

I want to call it like this:

```cpp
int x = foo(std::make_unique<int>(1));
```

But, it's giving this error:

```
Candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
```

I can fix it by providing the type T explicitly:

```cpp
int x = foo<int>(std::make_unique<int>(1));
```

Is it possible to fix it such that it can infer? The type is clearly embedded in the typename `U` but it does not seem to "propagate" to `T`.

Comment: SFINAE constraints don't participate in template argument deduction, they happen later. Perhaps you want `template <typename> typename T`, then `T<U> val` as a parameter?

Comment: Why both branches return`*val`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Sorry, I'm pretty new to c++ template programming. I cannot understand your suggestion. Could you provide concrete code sample?

Comment: @康桓瑋 It's just a made-up example since both possible types of U are smart pointers.

Comment: Added an answer. I had a better idea, so I did something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SFINAE constraints don't affect template argument deduction. Your compiler has to deduce `T` and `U` first, without even looking at your `enable_if_t<...>`.

I'd do something like this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

namespace impl
{
    template <typename A, template <typename...> typename B>
    struct specialization_of : std::false_type {};

    template <template <typename...> typename T, typename ...P>
    struct specialization_of<T<P...>, T> : std::true_type {};
}

template <typename A, template <typename...> typename B>
concept specialization_of = impl::specialization_of<A, B>::value;


template <typename T>
requires specialization_of<T, std::unique_ptr> || specialization_of<T, std::shared_ptr>
auto foo(T val)
{
    if constexpr (specialization_of<T, std::unique_ptr>)
    {
        return *val;
    }
    return *val;
}
```

---

> [I also want] `std::is_same_v<U, std::function<T()>>`

Then you need a specialized template just for this task. Something like:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct foo : std::false_type {};
template <typename T, typename U>
struct foo<std::function<T()>, U> : std::is_same<T, U> {};
```

Then `foo<std::function<int()>, int>` is true.

Comment: This works great, thanks! But I'm kinda stuck with C++17 for a while. Is there a version that doesn't use the concepts/requires syntax?

Comment: Haha never mind. I figured out! Thanks again.

Comment: My real-life problem is actually more complicated... For this signature, `T foo(U val)`, one of the possible types being passed is actually a `std::function` returning `T`. This template trick doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @fatdragon I don't fully understand, so I suggest asking a new question, and providing more details.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73089499/cannot-infer-template-argument-t-when-a-second-parameter-is-heterogenous-and-i

Comment: Much appreciated. It's getting late here (230am in Los Angeles)... I'll try your idea tomorrow.